# JavaScript 2D array iteration through one dimension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have an [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel)-based product list saved as .txt. I load this into JavaScript as follows:

```
function make2DArray (pfad){
    var Daten = loadFile(pfad);
    var Array = createArray(Daten);
    return Array;
}

function createArray(data_in){
    var Zeilen = data_in.split("\n");
    var Spalten = new Array();

    for (var i=0; i<Zeilen.length; i++)
    {
        Spalten = Zeilen[i].split("\t");
        Zeilen[i] = Spalten.splice(0, Spalten.length);
    }
    return Zeilen;
};

function loadFile(file_in)
{
    var file_out;
    $.ajax({
        type:     "GET",
        url:      file_in,
        dataType: 'text',
        async:    false,
        success:  function(data){
            file_out = data;
        },
        error: function(){
            openDialog('Datei nicht gefunden', file_in + " konnte nicht gefunden werden.\n<br />Bitte wende dich an einen Troubleshooter oder Teamleader!");
        }
    });

    return file_out;
};
```

That's so that you know how my Array is made...

Anyway, with this I have an Array[rows][cols] to work with. Now I have a price in array[rows][14] which I want to compare. I load one line which is the existing produkt (1D Array) and my 2D array:

```
function PackAusfiltern (arrzeile, arr) {
    var Eingabearray = arr;
    var Ausgabearray = "";

    var BestandPreis = arrzeile[14];
    BestandPreis = BestandPreis.replace(/\,/g, '.');
    BestandPreis = parseFloat(BestandPreis);
    //Here I get the price of the existing package which I want to compare
```

And now to my actual problem:
I want to literate through every row, get the value of column 14 and convert it to a number (some numbers are stored like "39,90", so I need to change the "," to ".").

I always get an error here in this line:

```
var zwischenspeicher = Eingabearray[i][14]+"";
```

It says something like "for the property '14' is no value get able" (German Internet Explorer 9...).

Here is the `for` loop which should get the value, make it a number, compare it an delete elements where the second line already brings the error:

```
for (var i=0, j=Eingabearray.length; i<j; i++) {
    var zwischenspeicher = Eingabearray[i][14]+"";
    zwischenspeicher = zwischenspeicher.split(',').join('.');
    zwischenspeicher = parseFloat(zwischenspeicher);
    Eingabearray[i][14] = zwischenspeicher;
    if ((BestandPreis <= Eingabearray[i][14]) && Eingabearray[i][16] == 1)
    {
    var löschenPO = Eingabearray.indexOf(Eingabearray[i][17]); // Find other pack code
    var löschenindex = Eingabearray.indexOf(löschenPO); // Search other pack
    Eingabearray = Eingabearray.splice(löschenindex, 1);    // Delete other pack
    }
 };
```

Just for information:

```
for (var i=0, j=Eingabearray.length; i<j; i++) {
  alert(Eingabearray[i][14]); //= '39.90'
```

and

```
type(Eingabearray[i][14]); //= [object Number]

function type(obj){
    alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj));
}
```

What stupid mistake have I made?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to insert an `if(Eingabearray[i])`, because the error came from some empty lines...

So:

```
for (var i=0, j=Eingabearray.length; i<j; i++) {

    if (Eingabearray[i]){

        if ((BestandPreis <= Eingabearray[i][14]) && Eingabearray[i][16] == 1)
        {
            var löschenPO = Eingabearray.indexOf(Eingabearray[i][17]); // Find other pack code
            var löschenindex = Eingabearray.indexOf(löschenPO); // Search other pack
            Eingabearray = Eingabearray.splice(löschenindex, 1);    // Delete other pack
        };
    };
};
```

now works fine.